# How to send png file using httpclient in java

Tags: java

```
[1] curl -v -X POST "someip/emailtemplate?mimeType=image/png" -H 'content-type: application/octet-stream' -k --data-binary '@image.jpg'

[2] curl -v -X POST "someip/emailtemplate?mimeType=image/png" -H 'content-type: application/octet-stream' -k --data-binary 'D:/myfolder/image.jpg'
```

Both commands runs successfully, But 2nd curl response shows the location which is invalid, 1st curl shows the valid location of image and when navigate to same it takes to the image.

However with 2nd when navigate to location it shows

```
"The image “https://location” cannot be displayed because it contains errors."
```

What's wrong with 2nd one when providing the absolute path instead of @image.jpg

I also need to automate the above in java, using below code, it get passed but images send using it are broken when navigate to the location received in response and shows the above error 'it contains errors'

```
public void sendPostForTemplate() throws Exception {
file = new File(directoryPath + "/path/Test.png");
FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY);
post = new HttpPost(URL);
client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
builder.addPart("my_file", fileBody);
builder.addBinaryBody("upstream", file, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, "Test.png");
post.setHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
entity = builder.build();
post.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
}
```

Comment: There are at least two separate questions here, and neither is answerable without some detail about what the server does.

Comment: I provided the code as well as curl commands, please let me know what else you need

Comment: You are asking a question about curl ( you need the `@` when you specify the file. Otherwise you just include the data, which you do not want to do. [ref](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)) Your other question is about making an http post request with java. They are two completely separate questions.

Comment: I have mentioned that i need to automate the above curl in java. I just provided the over information so that everything can be cleared. Still waiting for answer.

Comment: Is your curl question is sorted? For you java question, what gives you the error? When you try to view the image afterwards? What do you get in your `response` object? What about the `setMode call`? Did you consider trying, `HttpMultipartMode STRICT`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using .bat file. I had encountered the same issue in past and resolved it using .bat file.

You can also pass the arguments with bat script. Here is the sample example. Just save this using .bat and use below java code. It should work. However you can change the .bat script accordingly.

"test.bat":

```
@echo off 

SET firstparameter=%1
SET secondparameter=%2
ECHO %firstparameter%
ECHO %secondparameter%

curl -v -X POST "url/v1/media/%secondparameter%/emailtemplate?mimeType=image/png" -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" -k --data-binary "@image.png" -H "%firstparameter%"
```

"Java Code to execute above .bat script":

```
String filePath="\\test.bat";
File pathFile = new File(filePath);
Process process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{String.valueOf(pathFile),"parameter1","parameter2"});
BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
ost = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
String line;
while ((line = read.readLine()) != null) {
System.out.println("output is "+line);
}
read.close();
```